# Comparison of CSV rows with Python

Tags: python, csv

I sorted my CSV file to make some calculates. Python 2.7

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Cliente_x_Pais_Sitio.csv', sep=',')
df1 = df.sort_values(by=['Cliente','Auth_domain','Sitio',"Country"])
df1.to_csv('test.csv')
```

CSV data (`test.csv`):

```
Cliente,Fecha,Auth_domain,Sitio,Country,ECPM_medio
FF,15/12/2017,@ff,ff_Color,AfganistÃ¡n,0.53
FF,15/01/2018,@ff,ff_Color,AfganistÃ¡n,0.5
FF,15/01/2017,@ff,ff_Color,Alemania,0.34
FF,15/12/2017,@ff,ff_Color,Alemania,0.38
FF,15/01/2018,@ff,ff_Color,Alemania,0.37
```

What I need:

```
if (15/12/2017 ECPM) ≤ (15/01/2018 ECPM):
    if ((15/12/2017 ECPM)*0.8) ≥ (15/01/2017 ECPM):
        r = (15/01/2017 ECPM)
    else:
        r = ((15/12/2017 ECPM)*0.8)
else:
    if (15/01/2018 ECPM) ≥ (15/01/2017 ECPM):
        r = (15/01/2017 ECPM)
    else:
        r = (15/01/2018 ECPM)
```

Filling in the real data, the first two lines would be:

```
if 0.53 ≤ 0.5:
    if 0.5 ≥ 0: #if we don't have the cell value I would like to add a 0 True
        r = 0.5
```

Remember I have more than 10,000 rows son I need a multiple form

The new CSV should show me this:

```
Cliente,Auth_domain,Sitio,Country,Recomendation_ECPM
FF,@ff,ff_Color,AfganistÃ¡n,0.5
FF,@ff,ff_Color,Alemania,0.34
```

Comment: It's very difficult to me explain what I need because I'm not American! So, my apologies. `ECPM` is the `ECPM_Medio` column of my Original `CSV`. And about the `if - else`, if the `ECPM_Medio` value of `15/12/2017` is smaller than `ECPM_Medio` value of `15/01/2018`.... @pault

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I have the correct

1. date selection in `setval` or
2. the return value logic in `compare_val`

But the pipeline regardless of those uses sort, group_by, and transform. Because we'll compare the edges to `nan` (`shift(-1)` on first, and `shift(1)` on the end), we have to remove them at the end.

```
# build data
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""Cliente,Fecha,Auth_domain,Sitio,Country,ECPM_medio
FF,15/12/2017,@ff,ff_Color,AfganistÃ¡n,0.53
FF,15/01/2018,@ff,ff_Color,AfganistÃ¡n,0.5
FF,15/01/2017,@ff,ff_Color,Alemania,0.34
FF,15/12/2017,@ff,ff_Color,Alemania,0.38
FF,15/01/2018,@ff,ff_Color,Alemania,0.37
""")).sort_values(by='Fecha')

# functions to parse
def compare_val(cur,past,future):
   if cur <= past:
       cur_adj = cur * .8
       if cur_adj >= past:
            return(past)
       else:
            return(cur_adj)
   else:
        if future >= past:
           return(past)
        else:
           return(future)

def setval(v):
      cur, past, future = v, v.shift(-1), v.shift(1)
      v = [ compare_val(*x) for x in zip(cur,past,future)]
      return(v)

# do the work
df['Recomendation_ECPM'] = df.\
      groupby(['Cliente','Auth_domain','Sitio',"Country"])['ECPM_medio'].\
      transform(setval)

df[ pd.notna(df['Recomendation_ECPM']) ]
```

Comment: Thanks for trying but is not the exactly I`m looking for! If you see the results I need on the question, first, I need a new csv and also, I need to compare the `Fecha` through the same `Cliente, Auth_domain,Sitio,Country`

Comment: the `.groupby[...]` should limit the comparison to within those columns (Cliente, Auth, etc). 
add `.to_csv` on the last line to save the output to a file

Comment: if I want to save it i have an error: `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_save'`Also, please, print your results and you will see another answer that I'm not looking for

Comment: Please, see the file: First your answer, and second what I need https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rIhY8GdM2SRebiYcT8iX7iiPVj_IO0l6